# Trying to learn about abstract integration.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to learn some analysis from a book and some problem sets I have for it and inside the book. Sadly not very many have solutions and It seems I am a bit lost.

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on $R$.

Prove that the points of continuity of $f$
is a $G_{\delta}$ set by considering the sets $E_n$ where $E_n$ the set of all $a \in R$ such that there exists an open interval $J$ that includes $a$ and such that the difference between the sup
and the inf of $f$ on $J$ is $< \frac{1}{n}$

It seems to want me to show that limsup and liminf for each a is equal because of something to with $B(a,\frac{1}{n})$

Also i have no idea what $G_{\delta}$ is, it doesnt seem to be defined in my book and its not defined in the question.

The textbook I am studying from is
http://bass.math.uconn.edu/real.html It does request that the question be answered in the requested fashion for its teaching value but I don't particularly care as I can't answer a question I don't understand.

Comment: $G_\delta $ is defined in page 34, at the end

Comment: Ah, that explains why the problem seems to make no sense. Seems odd to have it on the first suggested problem set when it isn't defined until chapter 4. i read the first 3 and decided to give them a go clearly wasn't a good choice.

Comment: Is $R$ the set of all real numbers ?

Comment: i am assuming so based on the "real valued function" but its says R in bold.